# Why did Star Trek: Insurrection feature HMS Pinafore?

Tags: star-trek, music, star-trek-insurrection

In *Star Trek: Insurrection*, Captain Picard and Worf sing *A British Tar* from *HMS Pinafore* by Gilbert and Sullivan in an attempt to distract Data.

As Picard mentions in that scene, Data was rehearsing the song for a performance aboard the Enterprise.

However, **is there an out-of-universe reason why that specific operetta was chosen for the movie?**

[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/A_British_Tar) gives a hint that Patrick Stewart suggested *HMS Pinafore* (when the original plan for the scene was that they would recite from Shakespear's *King Lear*), apparently quoting the book *[Fade In: From Idea to Final Draft](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Fade_In:_From_Idea_to_Final_Draft#Fade_In:_From_Idea_to_Final_Draft.2C_The_Writing_of_Star_Trek_Insurrection)*.

Does the book *Fade In: From Idea to Final Draft* give any further details about that change?

Comment: LaForge sang "I Am the Very Model of a Modern Major-General" (also by Gilbert and Sullivan) in TNG: "Disaster". I wonder whether this is in any way related.

Comment: @Hilbert - Well, yes. In the sense that pretty much everyone involved with the production and writing would be familiar with Gilbert and Sullivan, just as they'd almost certainly know quite a lot of Shakespeare.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quote from that book is:

> ***Patrick was uncomfortable using Shakespeare in the ship battle with Data.
>   “I don’t think the Lear quotes work,” he’d said in his notes. “It will be
>   meaningless to most of our audience and I’m not sure I believe in what it is meant
>   to do.”***
>
> *The idea harkened back to the television series when Picard had taught
>   Data about humanity by directing him in fully-recreated scenes from
>   Shakespeare’s plays on the holodeck. We’d actually built one memorable
>   episode around the themes of Henry V. In addition, I thought the
>   King’s madness in Lear would provide a metaphor for Data’s erratic
>   behavior.*
>
> *Losing Shakespeare didn’t really bother me. But I felt we needed
>   something like it. I argued that Picard would try every trick to
>   safely capture Data before ever firing a weapon that might harm him.
>   Patrick suggested, **“Well, couldn’t I tell him some jokes that we
>   both know or perhaps sing something from Gilbert and Sullivan?”** And
>   a new sequence was born*

However, this conflicts with his past statements that he's just [not keen on their works](http://nicky_smith.tripod.com/sfx.html)

> *In the new Star Trek flick, Stewart's Picard has a lengthy scene with
>   Worf and Data in which they sing "A British Tar" from Gilbert &
>   Sullivan's HMS Pinafore. Again, to some surprise, it's not Stewart's
>   cup of tea.*
>
> ***"I'm sorry, but i really don't like Gilbert & Sullivan,"*** he says,
>   shaking his head between his hands. "It's like the Marx Brothers. I've
>   tried but I just don't get it."

Patrick Stewart tells the story very differently. Apparently he wasn't keen but all of [his other suggestions were dismissed](http://www.crankycritic.com/qa/startrek9/stewartqa3.html)

> *This is how it goes with putting movies together. Michael came up with
>   this idea of "OK how do we distract Data? take him off guard with
>   something that might just distract him for a moment". What he wrote
>   was Shakespeare, rehearsing him in a scene from King Lear. Oh God it
>   was deadly. It was nice, I mean King Lear's a great play but it's not
>   the moment you wanted to have there. I don't recall whose idea it was
>   but "maybe it's musical" came up. First of all, I said, anything that
>   Tony Bennett sings is what we should do, because Brent has this
>   beautiful tenor voice. They said it's obvious and corny and Rick is
>   always reluctant to make 20th century references so overtly. And then
>   **Michael came up with the G&S. Now, just like the Marx Brothers, I
>   don't get G&S. Never have. But I thought wait a minute I know what
>   they should sing! Picture Picard and Data singing [Three Little Maids](http://www.crankycritic.com/qa/startrek9/picard.wav) . And they said "no that's vulgar, Patrick." And they came up
>   with this song which I resisted and fought and said no it's boring but
>   I was wrong.** It's totally successful. So that's how the G&S came
>   about. It works nicely. You're right, the counterpoint of the G&S and
>   what they're actually doing is charming.*