# Lyric Mistake in HMS Pinafore?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-insurrection

When Picard, Data, and Worf sing HMS Pinafore, Picard says "his heart should stamp" during the second verse. Did he misspeak because those aren't the words?[image]

Comment: Nice catch! My +1.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Picard makes a mistake in the second verse (the lyrics of which we don't see on-screen). The line should be

> "His foot should stamp"

but he sings

> "His ***heart*** should stamp"

### In-universe explanation

Presumably this was due to the stress of trying to fly the shuttle, monitor the mooring clamps and sing, all at the same time.

### Out-of-universe explanation

This seems to just be a production goof (noting that [Stewart isn't a particular fan of Gilbert and Sullivan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113125/why-did-star-trek-insurrection-feature-hms-pinafore)). The [script](http://movies.trekcore.com/insurrection/script.txt) has the correct line.

> **PICARD:** (smiles, triumphant) *Prepare the docking clamps.*
>
> Worf moves to a rear panel as Picard sings with Data...
>
> **PICARD/ DATA'S COM VOICE:** *"... His foot should stamp..."*

As does the film's [official novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Insurrection_(novel))

> The captain grinned and in the same soft tone, told Worf- *“Prepare the
>   docking clamps.”* The Klingon obeyed as Picard sang, triumphant, with
>   his android friend: "*Or the tang of a tyrant tongue … **His foot should stamp** and his throat should growl, His hair should twirl and his face should scowl*"

Comment: It might be a good idea to point out that the lyrics on the screen are correct ones, just from a different verse.